# Progress Bar creation in React TS - getting error implicitly has type 'any' although types are declared in interface

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to recreate this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/QWjaMOM) in React Typescript. I renamed class to className and pasted the css into my App.css. I started to create the types in my interface and passed it on to my function. But still I am getting th errors that for example `previousTimestamp` and others have: `implicitly has type 'any' in some locations where its type cannot be determined.`

Why does it say it has any type when I say in my interface that it has number type?

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

export interface Props{
  reatTotal: number;
  apparentTotal: number
  pixelsProgressed: number;
  apparentPixelsProgressed: number;
  previousTimestamp: number;
  replayButton: HTMLElement;
}


function App(props: Props) {

// Internal store
let realTotal = 0;
let apparentTotal = 0;
let pixelsProgressed;
let apparentPixelsProgressed;
let previousTimestamp;

// Config
const pixelPerSecond = 50;
const depthExaggeration = 2;
const loaderHeight = 40;

// DOM elements
const stage = document.getElementById('stage');
const loader = document.getElementById('loader');
const apparentProgressText = document.getElementById('loader__text');
const replayButton = document.getElementById('control__replay');
const segments = document.querySelectorAll('.loader__segment');
const perspective = document.getElementById('perspective');

// Borrowed from https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294
function easeInOutQuad(t) {
    return t < 0.5 ? 2*t*t : -1+(4-2*t)*t;
}

function reset() {
    pixelsProgressed = 0;
    apparentPixelsProgressed = 0;
    previousTimestamp = null;
  
  segments.forEach(el => el.style.setProperty('--backgroundTranslateX', '-100%'));
}

function play() {
    reset();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--loaderHeight', `${loaderHeight}px`);
segments.forEach(el => {
    let { startX, endX, startZ, endZ } = el.dataset;
  
  startZ = (startZ ?? 0) * depthExaggeration;
  endZ = (endZ ?? 0) * depthExaggeration;
  
  let width = +endX - +startX;
  let translateZ = 0;
  let rotateY = 0;
  let transformOrigin = '50% 50%';
  
  if (startZ === endZ) {
    translateZ = -startZ;
    el.dataset.apparentStart = apparentTotal;
    apparentTotal += width;
    el.dataset.apparentEnd = apparentTotal;
  } else {
    const deltaZ = +endZ - +startZ;
    width = Math.abs(+endZ - +startZ);
    
    if (deltaZ > 0) {
        rotateY = 90;
        transformOrigin = '0 50%';
      translateZ = width - endZ;
    } else {
        rotateY = -90;
      transformOrigin = '0 50%';
      translateZ = -width - endZ;
    }
  }
  
  el.dataset.start = realTotal;
  realTotal += width;
  el.dataset.end = realTotal
  
  el.style.width = `${width}px`;
  el.style.transform = `translateX(${startX}px) translateZ(${translateZ}px) rotateY(${rotateY}deg)`;
  el.style.transformOrigin = transformOrigin;
  
  document.querySelector('#loader').style.width = `${apparentTotal}px`;
});

function setScale() {
    const stageWidth = stage.clientWidth;
  const stageHeight = stage.clientHeight;
  const stageAspectRatio = stageWidth / stageHeight;
  
  const loaderOuterWidth = apparentTotal;
  const loaderOuterHeight = loaderHeight * 4;
  const loaderAspectRatio = loaderOuterWidth / loaderOuterHeight;
  
  const constrain = 0.8;

  if (stageAspectRatio < loaderAspectRatio)
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scale', (stageWidth * constrain / loaderOuterWidth));
  else
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scale', (stageHeight * constrain / loaderOuterHeight));
}
setScale();
window.addEventListener('resize', () => setScale());

function step(timestamp) {
    if (!previousTimestamp)
    previousTimestamp = timestamp;
  
  pixelsProgressed += (timestamp - previousTimestamp) / 1000 * pixelPerSecond;
  const pixelsProgressedEased = easeInOutQuad(pixelsProgressed / realTotal) * realTotal;
  previousTimestamp = timestamp;
  
    segments.forEach(el => {
    const { start, end, apparentStart } = el.dataset;
    
    if (pixelsProgressedEased < +end && pixelsProgressedEased > +start) {
        const width = +end - +start;
      el.style.setProperty('--backgroundTranslateX', `${-width + pixelsProgressedEased - +start}px`);
        
      if (apparentStart)
        apparentPixelsProgressed = +apparentStart + (pixelsProgressedEased - +start);
      
    } else if (pixelsProgressedEased >= +start) {
      el.style.setProperty('--backgroundTranslateX', '0px');
    }
  });
  
  if (apparentPixelsProgressed > 0.995 * apparentTotal) {
    apparentPixelsProgressed = apparentTotal;
    apparentProgressText.innerText = 'Done!';
    replayButton.innerText = 'Replay';
    replayButton.disabled = false;
  } else {
    apparentProgressText.innerText = `Loading… ${Math.round(apparentPixelsProgressed / apparentTotal * 100)}%`;
    replayButton.innerText = 'Playing…';
    replayButton.disabled = true;
  }

  if (pixelsProgressed < realTotal)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

play();
replayButton.addEventListener('click', () => play());

stage.addEventListener('click', () => {
    stage.classList.toggle('is-isometric');
  perspective.checked = stage.classList.contains('is-isometric');
});
perspective.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (perspective.checked)
    stage.classList.add('is-isometric');
  else
    stage.classList.remove('is-isometric');
});

  return (
    <div id="container">
  <div id="stage">
    <div id="loader">
      <div id="loader__text">
        Loading&hellip;0%
      </div>

      <div className="loader__segment loader__segment--start" data-start-x="0" data-end-x="150"></div>

      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="150" data-end-x="150" data-start-z="0" data-end-z="25"></div>
      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="150" data-end-x="165" data-start-z="25" data-end-z="25"></div>
      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="165" data-end-x="165" data-start-z="25" data-end-z="0"></div>

      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="165" data-end-x="175"></div>

      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="175" data-end-x="175" data-start-z="0" data-end-z="50"></div>
      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="175" data-end-x="190" data-start-z="50" data-end-z="50"></div>
      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="190" data-end-x="190" data-start-z="50" data-end-z="-20"></div>

      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="190" data-end-x="225" data-start-z="-20" data-end-z="-20"></div>

      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="225" data-end-x="225" data-start-z="-20" data-end-z="10"></div>
      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="225" data-end-x="260" data-start-z="10" data-end-z="10"></div>
      <div className="loader__segment" data-start-x="260" data-end-x="260" data-start-z="10" data-end-z="0"></div>

      <div className="loader__segment loader__segment--end" data-start-x="260" data-end-x="300"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div id="footer__controls">
      <button type="button" id="control__replay">
        Replay
      </button>
      <label className="toggle">
        <input className="toggle__native" type="checkbox" id="perspective"/>
        <div className="toggle__control"></div>
        3D lock
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.css**

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
  color: #249353;
}

:root {
  --rotateX: 0;
  --rotateY: 0;
  --scale: 1;
  --translateY: 0;
  --loaderHeight: 0; /* Set by JS */
  --loaderColor: #3AD57C;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#stage {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  
  &:hover,
  &.is-isometric {
    --rotateX: -30deg;
    --rotateY: -45deg;
    --translateY: 35%;
  }
}

#loader {
  height: var(--loaderHeight);
  perspective: 100000px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform:
    scale(var(--scale))
    rotateX(var(--rotateX))
    rotateY(var(--rotateY))
    translateY(var(--translateY));
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#loader__text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-115%);
}

.loader__segment {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
  height: var(--loaderHeight);
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  --backgroundTranslateX: -100%;

  &.loader__segment--start {
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
  }

  &.loader__segment--end {
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
  }
  
  &::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: var(--loaderColor);
    content: '';
    transform: translateX(var(--backgroundTranslateX));
  }
}

#footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

#footer__controls {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  
  & > * {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
  }
}

#footer__credit {
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: .75em;
}

button {
  border: none;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: var(--loaderColor);
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 8em;
  
  &[disabled] {
    cursor: wait;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,0,0,.15) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%);
    background-size: 200% 200%;
    animation-name: buttonProgress;
    animation-duration: 1500ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  }
}

.toggle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #555;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  .toggle__native {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .toggle__control {
    width: 2em;
    height: 1em;
    margin-right: .5em;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #ddd;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    
    &::before {
      width: calc(1em - 2px);
      height: calc(1em - 2px);
      position: absolute;
      top: 1px;
      left: 1px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #fff;
      content: '';
      transition: left .25s ease-in-out;
    }
  }
  
  .toggle__native:checked + .toggle__control {
    background-color: var(--loaderColor);
    &::before {
      left: calc(100% - 1em + 1px);
    }
  }
}

@keyframes buttonProgress {
    0% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    55% { background-position: 0 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0 50%; }
}

@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #footer {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  #footer__credit {
    padding: 1em;
  }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing manual DOM manipulation with React. That is not good practice. You shouldn't use getElementById, innerHTML and such. Instead use React's DOM manipulation methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared types only for `props`, not your local variables.

```
export interface Props{
  previousTimestamp: number;
}

function App(props: Props) {
    props.previousTimestamp // this is typed (number)
    let previousTimestamp; // not this
}
```

To type your local variables, you'd do so during declaration.

`let previousTimestamp: number;`

#### Debugging

To debug these things, hover over your variable to see what TS thinks your types are. If you hover over `previousTimestamp` anywhere, you'd see it's `any`.

If you're using VSCode, I want to mention `inlays hints` you can enable which injects typing info of varying granularity into your editor. This can be overwhelming/annoying but also helps give you a sense of what types TS inferring.